# Change URL subdirectory and filename for 437 file requests

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have 437 URL requests which were static files on Movable Type, which can only be viewed on WordPress and in a different subfolder, with modified filenames. I have tried for days to make Rewrite and Redirect work, but no success.

Here is an example in my root `.htaccess` file of what I need to do (this didn't work, though).

RewriteRule

```
http://voidnow.org/archives/2012/08/divided-america.php
```

to

```
http://voidnow.org/WP-Void/2012/08/divided_america/
```

There are 4 changes to make:

- subdirectory `/archives/` changed to `/WP-Void/`
- `file-name-with-hyphens` changed to `file_name_with_underscores`
- `.php` lopped off filename
- slash added to end of line

I have the following lines at the top of my root `.htaccess`:

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
```

Please note that .php files no longer exist in the archives subdirectory. Not sure if that makes a difference, but, error logs for the failed rewrites begin by stating that the requested file is not found in the /archives/ subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^archives/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)-(.*).php /WP-Void/$1/$2/$3_$4/ [R=301,L]
```

it should redirect pages from:

```
http://voidnow.org/archives/2012/08/divided-america.php
```

to

```
http://voidnow.org/WP-Void/2012/08/divided_america/
```

Comment: Thank you, Howlin. It looks right, but, there is no change. Still getting 404 errors, e.g. /archives/2012/08/divided-america.php 216.177.182.134 http://voidnow.org/community/archives.php 404. Must be another problem within htaccess. Will do some other checking. Appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your htaccess file?

Comment: Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks


RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^voidnow\.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.voidnow\.org$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/voidnow\.org\/WP-Void\/" [R=301,L]


RewriteRule ^archives/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)-(.*).php /WP-Void/$1/$2/$3_$4/ [R=301,L]


<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>

Comment: Sorry, the htaccess contents got all run together when pasted into this comment box

Comment: Try move those two lines in my post above the other rewritecond/rule.

Comment: No change, Howlin. I am wondering if my htaccess file is even being processed. I am going to check the error log.

Comment: [Tue May 13 21:41:41 2014] [error] [client 216.177.182.134] File does not exist: /home/fbmritln/public_html/archives/2010, referer: http://voidnow.org/community/archives.php                                                                                                                           error log has the filename URL truncated.

Comment: What folder do you have the htaccess file in?

Comment: In my /public_html/ folder